newlines are removed when copying text from X11-application to a text-field in Firefox
With the latest versions of Firefox (e.g. 125.0.3), newlines are removed when copying text from X11-applications (e.g. Emacs) to a text-field in Firefox. An example: the field for typing a message on the page https://app.wire.com/. I’ve seen the problem also on other pages, but I don’t remember where.
I’ve tried Chromium: No problem, multi-line text is properly copied to text-fields.
How could I keep the line-break please with Firefox?
TIA for any hints, Peter
